# Sorting Records in apex:repeat by Date: Is It Possible?

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, repeat

I am currently working on a Visualforce page that utilizes an apex:repeat to display records from a custom object. I would like to know if there's a way to arrange these records in ascending or descending order based on their date field using the apex:repeat tag.

I have looked through the documentation and tried a few approaches, but I haven't been able to achieve the desired sorting. Is there a method or technique to accomplish this directly within the apex:repeat tag itself? If not, are there alternative methods that you would recommend?

Thank you for your time and assistance!

Comment: Using [order by](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_orderby.htm) in the Apex SOQL?

Answer (score 2):

No, `<apex:repeat>` has no ability to control the order of the things it iterates over.

As [the documentation for `<apex:repeat>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_repeat.htm) lays out, the only attributes it has are: first, id, rendered, rows, value, and var.
"first" and "rows" together control the *window* of the records that get rendered (alternatively, you can think of it like taking a slice of an array), but that doesn't affect the order of the underlying data that you pass in via `value`.

You need to do the sorting before handing the data over to `<apex:repeat>`. I believe that you'll need a custom controller or a controller extension to do that (where you'd be able to use the `ORDER BY` clause in your query, or create a class that implements the [Comparable interface](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_comparable.htm) to enable you to use the `.sort()` method on a `List<YourClass>`)

Comment: One could also choose to use JavaScript on the client and reorder the data after it's been given to the client. Or, indeed, one could use something like a jQuery sortable table or other frameworks.